# Why would a perfectly incompressible ball on a rough surface stop rolling?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction, torque, rotation

We know that the force that opposes the rolling of an object exists due to the deformation of the body's surface at the point of contact which creates a decelerating torque on the body.

What if the object is perfectly rigid such that it doesn't deform even a little? In this case, why does the object stop rolling (as there is no force/torque opposing it this time? Assume there is no air drag.

One reason I can think of is:

Rolling happens due to friction. So, continuously, a little heat energy is being lost at the expense of kinetic energy. This way, due to friction's inefficiency while causing the ball to roll, the ball stops after some time.

What are your opinions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A perfectly incompressible ball that experiences no air friction is an approximation to reality. This approximation disregards friction. So you should not expect it to give you realistic results about friction.

If you disregard all sources of friction and other loss, you would find the ball rolls forever.

Comment: I beg to differ. If you disregard ALL sources of friction, the ball wouldn't even roll in the first place (because there is no friction to create torque to initiate rolling). It would just slide along.
To make things clearer, I have modified the question to include "rough surface".

Comment: You don't have to disregard friction. Rolling without slipping involves static friction, not kinetic friction. Static friction doesn't consume energy. It's the same force that stops screws sliding out of things when they point downwards.

Answer (score 0):

> Rolling happens due to friction.

This is not true. [See my answer to a related question.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/807920/rotation-of-disc-on-smooth-surface/807956#807956)

If a ball is sliding along a slippery surface with translational motion but no rotation and then hits a rough patch, kinetic friction will induce the ball to start rotating until its angular velocity $\omega$ becomes equal to v/r and its motion can now be described as rolling without slipping. There is now only static friction acting. When the ball gets past the rough patch and is back on a frictionless surface, it will continue to roll along, rotating and translating with $\omega = v/r$. Friction is necessary to initiate rolling motion but it is not required to sustain it. You can convince yourself of this by rolling a ball on the surface of table. When the ball gets to the end of the table, it continues to rotate and translate horizontally. There is nothing to stop the rotation and $\omega$ remains equal to $v/r$.

A perfectly incompressible ball rolling on a rough surface that experiences no air friction will slow down if there is a gravitational field and if the surface is not also perfectly incompressible. Image a heavy wheel rolling on a layer of Styrofoam. It will leave an indentation in the Styrofoam that only slowly starts to regain its original shape long after the wheel has passed. The wheel expends energy compressing the foam layer and because the uncompressed foam in front of the wheel is higher than the compressed foam under the base of the wheel there is effectively an up ramp and the effect is like trying to roll up a slight incline which also slows down the ball. The foam is an extreme example to make it easier to visualise what is happening, but in reality, no surface is totally incompressible so there will always be this friction present. Another friction is static friction which counter intuitively, is always present even if a ball is rolling without slipping. If you imagine a box on a rough surface and apply a small force it will not move until the force overcomes the static friction. There are two aspects to this static friction. One is that the microscopic imperfections of the ball and the surface effectively create small interlocking teeth and the surfaces have to lift and skip over these microscopic teeth. This is only occurs when the rotation if the ball is not exactly $\omega = v/r$ and is attempting to slip, but for perfect rolling motion it is not relevant. During perfect rolling motion it is like a gear wheel running along a perfectly matching toothed rack. The second aspect of static friction as applied to rolling motion (which is better called rolling friction) is the 'stickiness of the surface. As a wheel makes contact with a fresh surface, tiny temporary molecular bonds are made and a moment later they are broken. This can be visualised as trying t roll a ball on a surface covered in glue. There is obvious expenditure of energy and an associated slow down, as the ball continuously detaches itself from the adhesive surface.

Friction is proportional to the normal force which is proportional the mass of the object and the acceleration of gravity. For this reason, rolling friction would be less on the moon all else being equal. To have no friction in a rolling situation, we need to remove gravity or have a perfectly incompressible ball and a perfectly incompressible surface (and no air of course). Unfortunately, in reality there is no such thing as a perfectly incompressible material just as there is no such thing as a perfectly rigid body.