# Rotation of disc on smooth surface

Tags: rotation

If we apply a force on the rim of a disc kept on a frictionless surface the disc rotates but can it be called rolling? Because what I know is that for rolling friction is necessary. Also can I consider the point of contact between the disc and surface be taken as instantaneous centre of rotation?

Comment: "Because what I know is that for rolling friction is necessary." in general static friction is necessary to initiate rolling but may not be necessary to maintain rolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for an object to be on a frictionless surface and have both translational and rotational motion, i.e. rolling with slipping.(now, if you launch a rotating disc onto a frictionless surface with the right initial conditions, you *can* have rolling without slipping) In the case of pure rotation the instantaneous center of rotation is at the center of the disc and not at the point of contact, however, if the disc rolls, then at any instant the center of rotation is at the point of contact.

Essentially, in order to be an instantaneous center of rotation, the velocity vectors of the points in the rigid body must for a *circular* field around the axis in question. In the case where the disc is rolling with slipping, There is at least one point on the line passing through the disc's center and perpendicular to the surface that is an ICR, i.e. the point where the magnitude of the velocity of translation equals the magnitude of the velocity of rotation. This point was brought to my attention by user @Zaph.

Comment: But if it rolls the centre moves with some acceleration then how can it be ICR, because ICR must be at rest?

Comment: @yyzr Yes, if it is rolling and not simply rotating, then the point of contact is the instantaneous center of displacement.

Comment: @yyzr However, the instantaneous center of rotation has to have zero velocity and not be simply at rest. Technically, the center of the disc can be at rest while rolling and yet it has translational velocity, so it is not the instantaneous center of rotation.

Comment: Ok but i think if it's rolling with slipping ICR can't lie on the point of contact since it slips. Am I right?

Comment: @yyzr Right. In this case the disc's instantaneous center of rotation is a pole at infinity, corresponding to the net transitional motion in the plane.

Comment: Both parts of this answer are wrong, no? 


The first part contradicts the answer of KDP, which I believe to be valid. 
“We can now insert our perfectly frictionless road, the disk will continue rolling without slippage and without friction. „
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/807956/325089


For the Second part, if rolling with slipping, from my understanding based on Wikipedia-defenition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation, there very much would be an ICR somewhere between the center of mass and the contact point and not only at infinity, why wouldn’t there?

Comment: @Zaph As far as rolling with slipping goes, can you point out an ICR other than at infinity?

Comment: So suppose your disc is rotating with a speed $v_e$ on its edge in its translational resting frame. Now suppose it is translating with a speed $|v| <  |v_e|$ in the direction, it would role in the slipping free case. There then at any time would exist a point in between the center of mass and the edge of the disc on the line perpendicular to $v$, that is at rest and all other parts seem to rotate around that point at that point of time (only at infinitesimal angle ofc, as the direction of the translation is not to be changed).

Comment: @Zaph Every point on the line has at least the velocity $v_e$,, since an IRC must have velocity of zero, I do not see your point.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus “Every point on the line has at least the velocity $v_e$“ That is not true $v_e$ is the speed of the edge points in the COM resting system. Even in that system the speed will vary if moving inward to the rotation center and reach zero there eventually. If you have an additional translational speed on top of that, it will reach zero at some point not on the COM where rotational and translational movement of the body cancel out.

Comment: @Zaph sorry, I meant $v$ not $v_e$. Why if the mass is rolling with slipping would any of the points on the mass have a zero velocity?

Comment: Because the bottom half of your discs movement due to rotations component parallel to the translation has a different sign then your translational movement. Therefore at some point on the disc they cancel out unless $v$ is larger then $v_e$.

Comment: @Zaph Got it, thanks! Boy, I was awful thick about that one!

Answer (score 3):

**Friction is not necessary for rolling motion.**

Consider a disk in space with no road surface. This is the perfect frictionless 'surface'. If we apply a force tangential to the perimeter of the disk at the top, (maybe have a peg sticking out of the disk so that the force makes good contact) the disk will acquire rotation and linear motion. The disk will now be rolling and friction at the base was not required to initiate the rolling motion  and friction is not required to sustain the rolling motion. If we accelerate the top of the disk to v, the centre of the disk will translate at v/2 and the angular velocity of the disk will be such that the base of the disk is always momentarily stationary ($\omega = v/r$).

We can now insert our perfectly frictionless road, the disk will continue rolling without slippage and without friction.

For more detail and calculations, [see my answer here to a related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/807730/how-does-rolling-without-slipping-happen-physically/807757?noredirect=1#comment1814410_807757).

In fact an object rolling without rolling friction (or other friction sources such as air friction) will continue its rolling motion indefinitely, while any rolling resistance will eventually bring the object to a stop, if there is no external energy input.

> Also can I consider the point of contact between the disc and surface
> be taken as instantaneous centre of rotation?

Short answer, yes. See comment and correction by @Zaph below.

> @KDP I am not sure if I am doing it right, but let us say we take a
> disc of mass "m" and radius "R" on a smooth surface and apply a force
> "F" on it for a time "t" tangentially. Then the final angular velocity
> with which it rotates after the removal of force is " 2Ft/mR " and
> final velocity of the centre of mass is " Ft/m " - yyzr.

In the reference frame where the centre of the disk is stationary, the change in angular momentum is equal to the input **angular** impulse, so $I \ \omega = FRt,$ so the resulting angular velocity is

$$\omega = \frac {F t R}{I}$$

For a disk, the moment of inertia is $I = \frac12 m R^2$ so

$$\omega = \frac {2 F \ t}{m\ R}$$

and our results now agree at this point (I corrected my earlier error).

> Now if it's rolling without slipping the COM must have velocity equal
> to " angular velocity × radius " wrt the ICR i.e the point of contact
> at the bottom. That way velocity= " 2Ft/m ", which is not equal to
> what I calculated earlier – yyzr

Using my previous result for the angular velocity,

$$v_{com} = \omega \times R = \frac {2 \ F \ t}{m}$$

(and we are now in agreement here also).

If you describe how you obtained your alernative result of v = FT/m we might be able to find where the discrepancy arises.

> @KDP acceleration of com= F/m, final velocity using v=u+at, becomes Ft/m,  - yyzr

That calculation is only valid if the force vector is directly inline with the com, which is not the case here. You have to work in terms of torque here. Think of the point of contact at the ICR as the instantaneous fulcrum of a lever. The force is applied at the top so the lever arm is 2R there and since the com is at distance R from the instantaneous fulcrum, the force applied to the com is 2F, so acceleration of the com is 2F/m. Using v= u + at, the velocity of the com is:

$$v_{com} = at = \frac {2 \ F \ t}{m},$$

which agrees with the result we obtained earlier.

Comment: Do you conclude that the free disc acquires translational and rotational motion based on conservation of angular momentum?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus Yes, based on conservation of angular momentum and linear momentum separately and on conservation of total linear and angular kinetic energy. All these conditions have to be satisfied. See my other answer I linked to ;-)

Comment: You are aright about the choice of reference point for your angular momentum. But “Instant centre of rotation” seems to have a sharply defined meaning, which from my understanding you can not apply to any arbitrarily chosen point. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation

Comment: @Zaph Thanks :-) I defer to your argument on the semantics of that point and have deleted that part, as it not the main crux of my answer.

Comment: I don't think I agree with this, because translation plus rotation does not necessarily constitute "rolling." Rolling means the rotation rate $\omega$ and the forward velocity $v$ are related by $\omega = v/r$.  A "no slip" condition against a mating surface is required for this

Comment: @RC_23   "Rolling means the rotation rate ω and the forward velocity v are related by ω=v/r". That is exactly what we get when a tangential force is applied to the disk with or without a surface. $\omega$ and $v$ are defined relative to a coordinate system, not a surface. If an object is rolling with $\omega = v/r$ on a frictionless surface it is rolling without slippage. Slippage usually means motion between the point of contact and the surface and usually results in wasted energy due to the kinetic friction, but there is no wasted energy in the extreme case that the surface is frictionless.

Comment: @RC_23 If a disk is rolling without slipping then $\omega = v/r$ and the rolling friction is proportional to the normal force $m g$. if we gradually reduce the gravity field to zero the rolling friction goes to zero, but the disk continues in its rolling motion. Removing the friction does not stop the rolling motion.

Comment: If I applied a force to a spool of wire in outer space, by pulling the wire tangential to the spool (only for an instant, and then the wire was cut), it would acquire a $\omega$ and $v$ entirely dependent on the relative mass and moment of inertia of the object. They would not be related by $\omega =v/r$ except by coincidence. I would not call this behavior rolling.  In your example, you utilized a frictional surface to start up the $\omega =v/r$ motion and then simply let it continue

Comment: I think we are in agreement on the physical phenomena, but pedagogically for the questioner, I think it's truest to say a frictional surface is necessary for rolling, apart from very contrived circumstances.

Comment: "If I applied a force to a spool of wire in outer space, by pulling the wire tangential to the spool .... They would not be related by ω=v/r,  except by coincidence." Actually they would be related by ω=v/r as per rolling motion without slippage, every single time. Unavoidable. Your method is exactly the way to do it.  Alternatively, have a thread wrapped around the perimeter of the disk, that has a loose loop on the end that hooks on a peg in the perimeter and slips off at the right moment. The perimeter of the disk can be completely frictionless.

Comment: @KDP I am not sure if I am doing it right, but let us say we take a disc of mass "m" and radius "R" on a smooth surface and apply a force "F" on it for a time "t" tangentially. Then the final angular velocity with which it rotates after the removal of force is " 2Ft/mR " and final velocity of the centre of mass is " Ft/m ". Now if it's rolling without slipping the COM must have velocity equal to " angular velocity × radius " wrt the ICR i.e the point of contact at the bottom. That way velocity= " 2Ft/m ", which is not equal to what I calculated earlier

Comment: @yyzr I have added a section to my answer to address your concerns.

Comment: @KDP acceleration of com= F/m, final velocity using v=u+at, becomes Ft/m, also the velocity you calculated is dimensionally incorrect because u have put impulse in place of angular impulse in the first equation

Comment: @yyzr I have responded again in my answer. We had both made errors and I have corrected my answer to use angular impulse as you correctly pointed out. It all seems to work out nicely now. Hope you can agree.

Comment: @KDP from what I have studied $F_{ext}=ma_{cm}$, by that acceleration should be $\dfrac{F}{m}$

Answer (score 0):

This is meant to supplement the other fine answers already given:

A purely rolling disk or wheel is a combination of linear and rotational motion with important restrictions:

1. The rotation is about center of mass of the wheel
2. The translational motion is measured from the center of mass of the wheel.
3. The ratio of translational velocity v and angular velocity $\omega$ is equal to the radius R:
   $$ \frac v {\omega} = R$$

This definition allows for pure rolling motion without a surface. If a disc is flying though space and meets these conditions then its motion is pure rolling.

Number 3 is important. If

$$ \frac v {\omega} < R$$ then the wheel spinning at a high rate but there is little forward motion. Like wheels of a car spinning on ice when one stomps on the accelerator. This is not pure rolling. If

$$ \frac v {\omega} > R$$ then the translational velocity is high and the wheel is barely spinning. Like a car that slides while applying the brakes. This is not pure rolling.